# Labview .VI application from Window to Linux application

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, labview

Due to now I just finish my application .VI and compile .exe (Windows with Labview).
Then if I want to take my application from windows to linux. And running on linux without MONO or Wine. Because I want to interface with NI-6008. 
How can I do?(Step by step)

Please help me. Thank You.

Comment: If you are at an educational institution or similar it might be worth checking whether you have a site-wide licence that includes LabVIEW for Linux as well as Windows. Also check the versions of Linux that LabVIEW actually supports at http://www.ni.com/labview/os-support/ - it may not be worth going down this road if the version you want to use is unsupported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, LabVIEW does not offer Windows->Linux cross-compilation [e.g. see here](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/how-to-cross-compile-a-VI/td-p/1290490). So you must have a licensed and installed version of LabVIEW for Linux. Then you move the project files (or just the VI file) and build it anew in Linux.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the [NI LabWindows™/CVI™ Run-Time Module for Linux](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/2823/en/), you use a Windows machine to compile to supported Linux distributions.

Comment: The question is about LabVIEW, not LabWindows/CVI.